# Check if displayName in users is unique Firebase & Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Just before adding a new user to firebase, I want to check if the displayName already exists for an other user. I'm storing the displayName in `users`:

```
root / users / document *(uid as id)* / fields *like uid, displayName, email, ...*
```

I've tried it like this:

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
import { User } from "./user";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';

...

constructor(
    public firestore: AngularFirestore,
    public firebase: AngularFireDatabase,
    public ngFireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    public router: Router,
    public ngZone: NgZone,
    public toastController: ToastController
  ) {
    this.getUserData();
    this.newUser = {} as newUser;
  }

...

  check_displayName() {
    var usersRef = this.firestore.collection("users");
    usersRef.where(doc.forEach(doc => doc, '==', this.state.displayName)).get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.empty) {
              console.log('displayName is unique', snapshot.empty)
              return false
        } else {
              return true
              console.log('displayName already exists')
        }
      })
  }
```

But I get an issue:

> ReferenceError: doc is not defined

How can I iterate through the docs when there are unique document-ids (uid)?

Thx for your hints

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to put a forEach inside of a where clause.  What are you trying to pass to where()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this ??

```js
check_displayName(userNameToCheck) {
    const usersRef = this.afStore.collection("users");
    usersRef.where('displayName', '==', userNameToCheck).get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            if (snapshot.empty) {
                console.log('displayName is unique', snapshot.empty);
                return false;
            } else {
                console.log('displayName already exists');
                return true;
            }
        });
}
```

I think you need to get the snapshot first and check if it is empty. There is no meaning in iterating through all docs and increasing your Firestore Reads.

And regarding the `forEach()`, first you need to get the snapshot and then use something like `snapshot.forEach()`. But in your case, if the snapshot is empty the username is unique and you did you job with just 1 read cost.

Small Tip: I have not checked if username comparision is case-sensitive. So I keep another field named `displayNameLower` and then compare that with lower-cased version of username to check.

Something like; `.where('displayNameLower', '==', userNameToCheck.toLowerCase())`

Comment: Thx! I've tried it but I get 'usersRef.where is not a function'. I think the problem that 'where' trying to access the documents: root / collection 'users' / documents 'uid' / fields 'e.g. displayName'

Comment: @mm1975 can you try using `firebase.firestore().collection()` ???

Comment: I've tried it but without success. 'afStore' stands for AngularFirestore

Comment: @mm1975 oh okay. Can you show me if you have installed Firebase SDK correctly and imported those successfully?

Comment: @mm1975 if the answer helped you make sure you accept it by clicking the TICK icon and upvote if you like. So that others know the issue is solved

Answer (score 1):

The solutiion above by Dharmaraj is pretty okay. But I would like to add further to it. We can make use of  `limit()` so that the firebase stops querying once any first matching  document from collection is found.If fastens the querying ultimately.

```
    const firebaseAdmin = require('firebase-admin');
    firebaseAdmin.initializeApp();
    const afStore = firebaseAdmin.firestore();

    check_displayName(userNameToCheck) {
        
        const userRef = this.afStore.collection("users");
        userRef.where('displayName', '==', userNameToCheck).limit(1).get()
            .then(snapshot => {
                if (snapshot.empty) {
                   console.log('displayName is unique', snapshot.empty)
                   return false

               } else {
                    console.log('displayName already exists')
                    return true
              }
            })
           .catch(err => {
            console.log('Alert:: error in querying the users document');
           });;
    }
```

Comment: If you are using this from the first release of the app then I assume there will be only 1 such Document in ideal condition.  But no issues using that . Ultimately it will return only 1 doc if exists even without using limit()

Comment: Secondly, we just need to to check if the doc is present or not so we don't need that snapshot.forEach() ... Only if-else is enough in that case

Comment: we just need to to check if the doc is present or not so we don't need that snapshot.forEach(). Yeah, you are correct. Thanks !